# Excel advanced lookup/reference formula required

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am trying to lookup a value in one sheet based on three criteria. The lookup formula resides in the *Operational Data* sheet which contains data from the machine which reports every ten minutes and has a structure similar to the table below (simplified for the sake of simplification)

```
DateTime                  Status   =>   ShouldBe
01/12/2010  01:00:01      ?             16
01/12/2010  02:00:01      ?             16
01/12/2010  03:00:01      ?             16
01/12/2010  04:00:01      ?             0
01/12/2010  05:00:01      ?             0
01/12/2010  06:00:01      ?             0
...
08/12/2010  07:00:01      ?             204
```

The *Status* column should reference the *Status Data* sheet which contains data of the machine's operating status. This only reports change in the machine's status, ie is not periodic. The *Status Data* sheet has a structure similar to that below (again simplified for the sake of simplification)

```
Error Code        Start Time                       End Time
16                01/12/2010  00:00:01             01/12/2010  03:08:56
0                 01/12/2010  03:08:56             06/12/2010  12:01:21
204               06/12/2010  12:01:21             15/12/2010  01:14:01
0                 15/12/2010  01:14:01             20/12/2010  09:12:42
```

Any ideas?

-- edit

From a quick web search there appers to be two approaches to lookup with mulitple criteria. This first being to add another column of concatenated valeus and using VLOOKUP on a concatenated string. This is not appropriate because I am trying to search based on < and > (less/greater then) on the date columns.

I couldn't figure out how to use MATCH for this because the third argument defines weather the LOOKUP is a a greater/less than and I can't combine the two.

For example:

'Operation Data'!DateTime > 'Status Data'!StartTime **and** 'Operation Data'!DateTime < 'Status Data'!EndTime

Comment: If the structure of your sample data resembles the real one, it seems you can use VLOOKUP on the BEGIN TIME column and disregard the END column. Just because the END contains the same time than the next BEGIN.

Comment: Its not clear from your data why 01/12/2010  00:40:01, 01/12/2010  00:50:01, and 01/12/2010  00:60:01 should be 0.  These all fall in the time range for code 16.  Also, looking at the error code data the end time for one row seems to always be the start time for the next.  If this is the case then end time can be ignored and a simple Match/Index formula will return the error code.  Could be something important has been lost in the simplification?

Comment: @chris neilsen I have edited the table so that codes correspond to times. It is correct that status updates are continuous, EndTime is the same as the next BeginTime. Can you provide an example of a Match/Index formula that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on sheet 'Status' Error codes are in Column A and Start time in Column B

on sheet 'Operational Data' DateTime is in column A

Formula is, for a cell in row 2

```
INDEX('Status'!$A:$A,MATCH(A2,'Status'!$B:$B,1))
```

Assumes data in sheet 'Status' is sorted ascending on Start Time

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of options:

1) You add a new column which is a concatenation of your 3 lookup criteria and do your lookup based on this.

2) The second option is an INDEX MATCH array formula, there is an example on here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46692&page=1

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into both those solutions before posting here. I have edited the question to addess this. For reference the formula I cannot make work is MATCH(1;(ErrorStartTime>'10 Minute Data'!B2)*(ErrorEndTime<'10 Minute Data'!B2)*(Status=5);0)